# How to highlight a button based on the format in the text content?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement where I have to highlight the appropriate button based on the format of the word selected in the textarea.
For instance,

```
If i have a text inside the textarea like, I am a new _text area_.
and if user clicks on the word _text area_ or brings the cursor point over that text the button bold should be highlighted, as the word is enclosed within _ .
```

I tried to use onclick event to get the index and traverse the string using regex .However it doesn't seem to work.Could anyone suggest me how to do this?

```js
var getFormat = function(event) {
  var element = document.getElementById('editor');
  console.log('editor', element);
  var startIndex = element.selectionStart;
  console.log('startIndex', startIndex);
  var selectedText = element.value.slice(startIndex);
  var stringMatch = selectedText.match(((\ * )\ 2)(.* ? )\ 1));
console.log('stringMatch', stringMatch);

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <textarea onclick='getFormat(event);' rows='10' cols='10' id='editor'></textarea>
  <button>Bold</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please try to rephrase your query, as to what needs to be highlighted and when ? maybe also give a more detailed description of what "is happening" and what "should happen"